# MISSING_LIBRARIES Error when using HERE Maps and Card.io on Android

Tags: android, here-api, card.io

I am getting a `MISSING_LIBRARIES` error on an activity that has a HERE Maps fragment, the error is coming from HERE Maps whenever it tries to initialize the map through the `init()` method and then `onEngineInitializationCompleted` gets called with the error code `MISSING_LIBRARIES`. It works fine until I added card.io dependency on build.gradle file.

So I am using card.io version 5.1.2 and the HERE Maps version is 3.0.2 Premium SDK for Android. minSdkVersion for Android is 14

What should I do to stop the card.io dependency from conflicting with HERE Maps?

**build.gradle script file**

```
buildscript {
    repositories {
        mavenCentral()
        jcenter()
    }

    dependencies {
        classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:1.3.1'
        classpath 'com.google.gms:google-services:1.3.0-beta1'
    }
}

apply plugin: 'com.android.application'
apply plugin: 'com.google.gms.google-services'

android {
    compileSdkVersion 22
    buildToolsVersion '21.1.2'

    defaultConfig {
        minSdkVersion 14
        targetSdkVersion 22
        versionCode getBuildNumber()
        versionName "3.0.0"
        applicationId "com.example"
        testInstrumentationRunner "android.support.test.runner.AndroidJUnitRunner"
        multiDexEnabled false
    }

    packagingOptions {
        exclude 'META-INF/NOTICE'
        exclude 'META-INF/LICENSE'
        exclude 'META-INF/LICENSE.txt'
        exclude 'META-INF/NOTICE.txt'
    }
}

dependencies {
    repositories {
        mavenCentral()

        flatDir {
            dirs 'lib'
        }
    }

    compile 'com.android.support:multidex:1.0.0'
    compile 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:22.2.0'
    compile 'com.android.support:cardview-v7:22.2.0'
    compile 'com.android.support:recyclerview-v7:22.2.0'
    compile 'com.android.support:design:22.2.0'
    compile 'com.squareup.okhttp:okhttp:2.4.0'
    compile 'org.roboguice:roboguice:3.0.1'
    compile 'io.card:android-sdk:5.1.2'
    provided 'org.roboguice:roboblender:3.0.1'
    compile 'uk.co.chrisjenx:calligraphy:2.1.0'
    compile 'com.google.code.gson:gson:2.3.1'
    compile files('lib/HERE-sdk.jar')
    compile 'com.google.guava:guava:18.0'
    compile 'com.wdullaer:materialdatetimepicker:1.4.2'
    compile 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-analytics:7.8.0'
    compile 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-gcm:7.8.0'
    compile 'com.pubnub:pubnub-android:3.7.5'
    compile 'org.joda:joda-convert:1.8'
    compile 'org.joda:joda-money:0.10.0'
    compile ('commons-validator:commons-validator:1.4.1'){
        transitive = false
    }

}
```

Comment: Can you post the build gradle script?

Comment: Thanks, I have updated the question with my build.gradle script file.

Comment: How do you know that card.io is conflicting?  If you're able to reproduce this with a simpler example, please provide the sample project so we can better help.

Comment: take a look at this link :

http://stackoverflow.com/questions/35218242/here-maps-android-integration-missing-libraries-error

Answer (score 0):

Check your manifest.xml file. Add below permissions under manifest tag.

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION"/>
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE"/>
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_NETWORK_STATE"/>
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.CHANGE_NETWORK_STATE"/>
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET"/>
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_WIFI_STATE"/>
```