# HERE Maps initialize Map Fragment MISSING_LIBRARIES Error

Tags: android, here-api

I get this error when trying run the application in device with API level 21 and 22(lolipop)
but the initialize Map Fragment work well in API 18 and 19(KitKat).
anyone have idea about this?

the logcat here

02-22 13:34:31.960 2346-2346/? I/art: Not late-enabling -Xcheck:jni (already on) 02-22 13:34:32.030 2346-2352/? I/art: Ignoring second debugger -- accepting and dropping 02-22 13:34:32.030 2346-2352/? E/art: Failed sending reply to debugger: Broken pipe 02-22 13:34:32.030 2346-2352/? I/art: Debugger is no longer active 02-22 13:34:32.040 2346-2352/? W/art: Suspending all threads took: 10ms 02-22 13:34:32.100 2346-2346/? W/System.err: org.xml.sax.SAXParseException: Unexpected end of document 02-22 13:34:32.100 2346-2346/? W/System.err: at org.apache.harmony.xml.parsers.DocumentBuilderImpl.parse(DocumentBuilderImpl.java:125) 02-22 13:34:32.100 2346-2346/? W/System.err: at javax.xml.parsers.DocumentBuilder.parse(DocumentBuilder.java:107) 02-22 13:34:32.100 2346-2346/? W/System.err: at com.nokia.maps.fi.a(XmlToDocParser.java:24) 02-22 13:34:32.100 2346-2346/? W/System.err: at com.nokia.maps.ResourceManager.a(ResourceManager.java:212) 02-22 13:34:32.100 2346-2346/? W/System.err: at com.nokia.maps.ResourceManager.a(ResourceManager.java:138) 02-22 13:34:32.100 2346-2346/? W/System.err: at com.nokia.maps.as.(GLConfigHelper.java:38) 02-22 13:34:32.100 2346-2346/? W/System.err: at com.nokia.maps.y.a(BaseTextureView.java:61) 02-22 13:34:32.100 2346-2346/? W/System.err: at com.nokia.maps.y.(BaseTextureView.java:54) 02-22 13:34:32.100 2346-2346/? W/System.err: at com.nokia.maps.bx.(MapTextureView.java:36) 02-22 13:34:32.100 2346-2346/? W/System.err: at com.here.android.mpa.mapping.MapView.a(MapView.java:320) 02-22 13:34:32.100 2346-2346/? W/System.err: at com.here.android.mpa.mapping.MapView.(MapView.java:169) 02-22 13:34:32.100 2346-2346/? W/System.err: at com.nokia.maps.bk.a(MapFragmentImpl.java:143) 02-22 13:34:32.100 2346-2346/? W/System.err: at com.here.android.mpa.mapping.MapFragment.onCreateView(MapFragment.java:147) 02-22 13:34:32.100 2346-2346/? W/System.err: at android.app.Fragment.performCreateView(Fragment.java:2220) 02-22 13:34:32.100 2346-2346/? W/System.err: at android.app.FragmentManagerImpl.moveToState(FragmentManager.java:949) 02-22 13:34:32.100 2346-2346/? W/System.err: at android.app.FragmentManagerImpl.moveToState(FragmentManager.java:1126) 02-22 13:34:32.100 2346-2346/? W/System.err: at android.app.FragmentManagerImpl.addFragment(FragmentManager.java:1228) 02-22 13:34:32.100 2346-2346/? W/System.err: at android.app.FragmentManagerImpl.onCreateView(FragmentManager.java:2201) 02-22 13:34:32.100 2346-2346/? W/System.err: at android.app.FragmentController.onCreateView(FragmentController.java:98) 02-22 13:34:32.100 2346-2346/? W/System.err: at android.app.Activity.onCreateView(Activity.java:5546) 02-22 13:34:32.100 2346-2346/? W/System.err: at android.support.v4.app.BaseFragmentActivityHoneycomb.onCreateView(BaseFragmentActivityHoneycomb.java:34) 02-22 13:34:32.100 2346-2346/? W/System.err: at android.support.v4.app.FragmentActivity.onCreateView(FragmentActivity.java:79) 02-22 13:34:32.100 2346-2346/? W/System.err: at android.view.LayoutInflater.createViewFromTag(LayoutInflater.java:754) 02-22 13:34:32.100 2346-2346/? W/System.err: at android.view.LayoutInflater.createViewFromTag(LayoutInflater.java:704) 02-22 13:34:32.100 2346-2346/? W/System.err: at android.view.LayoutInflater.rInflate(LayoutInflater.java:835) 02-22 13:34:32.100 2346-2346/? W/System.err: at android.view.LayoutInflater.rInflateChildren(LayoutInflater.java:798) 02-22 13:34:32.100 2346-2346/? W/System.err: at android.view.LayoutInflater.parseInclude(LayoutInflater.java:971) 02-22 13:34:32.100 2346-2346/? W/System.err: at android.view.LayoutInflater.rInflate(LayoutInflater.java:831) 02-22 13:34:32.100 2346-2346/? W/System.err: at android.view.LayoutInflater.rInflateChildren(LayoutInflater.java:798) 02-22 13:34:32.100 2346-2346/? W/System.err: at android.view.LayoutInflater.parseInclude(LayoutInflater.java:971) 02-22 13:34:32.100 2346-2346/? W/System.err: at android.view.LayoutInflater.rInflate(LayoutInflater.java:831) 02-22 13:34:32.100 2346-2346/? W/System.err: at android.view.LayoutInflater.rInflateChildren(LayoutInflater.java:798) 02-22 13:34:32.100 2346-2346/? W/System.err: at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:515) 02-22 13:34:32.100 2346-2346/? W/System.err: at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:423) 02-22 13:34:32.100 2346-2346/? W/System.err: at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:374) 02-22 13:34:32.100 2346-2346/? W/System.err: at android.support.v7.app.AppCompatDelegateImplV7.setContentView(AppCompatDelegateImplV7.java:256) 02-22 13:34:32.100 2346-2346/? W/System.err: at android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity.setContentView(AppCompatActivity.java:109) 02-22 13:34:32.100 2346-2346/? W/System.err: at com.student.fyp.MainActivity.onCreate(MainActivity.java:109) 02-22 13:34:32.100 2346-2346/? W/System.err: at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:6237) 02-22 13:34:32.100 2346-2346/? W/System.err: at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1107) 02-22 13:34:32.100 2346-2346/? W/System.err: at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2369) 02-22 13:34:32.100 2346-2346/? W/System.err: at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2476) 02-22 13:34:32.100 2346-2346/? W/System.err: at android.app.ActivityThread.-wrap11(ActivityThread.java) 02-22 13:34:32.100 2346-2346/? W/System.err: at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1344) 02-22 13:34:32.100 2346-2346/? W/System.err: at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102) 02-22 13:34:32.100 2346-2346/? W/System.err: at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:148) 02-22 13:34:32.100 2346-2346/? W/System.err: at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5417) 02-22 13:34:32.100 2346-2346/? W/System.err: at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method) 02-22 13:34:32.100 2346-2346/? W/System.err: at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:726) 02-22 13:34:32.100 2346-2346/? W/System.err: at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:616) 02-22 13:34:32.160 2346-2359/? D/OpenGLRenderer: Use EGL_SWAP_BEHAVIOR_PRESERVED: true 02-22 13:34:32.160 2346-2346/? I/System.out: ERROR: MISSING_LIBRARIES 02-22 13:34:32.200 2346-2359/? I/OpenGLRenderer: Initialized EGL, version 1.4 02-22 13:34:32.240 2346-2359/? W/EGL_emulation: eglSurfaceAttrib not implemented 02-22 13:34:32.240 2346-2359/? W/OpenGLRenderer: Failed to set EGL_SWAP_BEHAVIOR on surface 0x7fd678ed98c0, error=EGL_SUCCESS

Comment: i just follow the documentation here https://developer.here.com/mobile-sdks/documentation/android-hybrid-plus/topics/app-simple-android-studio.html

Comment: You get **what** error? Logcat please?

Comment: I/System.out: ERROR: MISSING_LIBRARIES

Comment: Possible duplicate of [HERE Maps Android Integration, MISSING\_LIBRARIES Error](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/35218242/here-maps-android-integration-missing-libraries-error)

Answer (score 0):

Can you please unzip your APK file?

Does the file contain the following:

```
/libs/armeabi-v7a/libMAPSJNI.so
/libs/armeabi-v7a/libMapsEngineResources.so
/libs/armeabi-v7a/lib ....
```

If your APK does not contain the native libraries it will result in the error above.

Comment: hope /libs/armeabi-v7a/libMapsEngineResourcesPkg.so for 3.+